# How to remove duplicates in a data frame with a different format?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So, I'm going through a dataset I saw on the internet, and I noticed lots of duplicates but with different formatting. For example, in the name column, some people started typing their name in LN, FN, MI, while some people typed their name in FN, MI, LN format. How can I remove these duplicates? Thank you!

Below is an example of a column in the data frame.

| Name |
| --- |
| Doe, John D. |
| John D. Doe |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be best to process that column so everything is in the same format. For names, it should be pretty straightforward since anytime the last name is written first there will be a comma after it. Something like this should be pretty close, then you can remove duplicates. (The `lstrip` string method just removes leading whitespace.)

```py
new_names = []
for name in df["Name"]:
    split_name = name.split(",")
    if len(split_name) > 1:
        name = " ".join([split_name[1].lstrip(), split_name[0]])
    new_names.append(name)
```

Note: this is definitely not the most time or memory-efficient method of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to this could be to try and get the format to a standardized form by using apply as follows : [image]

Explanation:

1. With apply we are able to perform an operation on each row in that column, represented by x.
2. First we replace the punctuations using replace('what to replace' ,'what to replace with') and get rid of the commas and periods. A regex can also be used
3. Then we apply a split(' ') to get a list of just the names which would look like this ['Doe', 'John', 'D'] for the first row and ['John', 'D', 'Doe'] for the second row
4. Then by sorting the list we get both lists to have the same order ['D', 'Doe', 'John'] and when we say both list we say that because there are only two rows in this example, apply will do this for each row
5. Finally we use a ' '.join() externally to convert the list style representation back to string  resulting in column now having the name in the same format in the same order. We then assign this back to the list to replace it in place

Now using the drop_duplicates() method we can get rid of the duplicates

Note that this method will not work if the names do not have the same set of strings. For example if one was Doe John D and the other was Doe John Denis one would have to be more careful as to how to identify and weed them out.

Also some advice for future posts, it is always good to post what you have tried and why that did not work. Cheers !